# How to save and fetch user search history on web apl

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

am working on a navigation web app. And I want to save user search history and display them on the search page. Can I do that without the user logged in.

Comment: Well make a cookie save the history there? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score -1):

Apart from cookies that @Alex mentioned, there is something called [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in javascript that enables you to store some data on the computer of your user. These would be the most convenient way to implement search history without involving any login or server-side stuff.

Comment: Thank you I will try them out